# How to safely double-encrypt a secret?

Tags: encryption, aes, public-key, key-escrow

Imagine two persons: Alice and Bob. We have a generated secret value that is valuable and has to be encrypted in a way that both can't reveal the value on their own but only when they both confirm.

My first approach would have been to double encrypt the secret value. One time with Alice keyset and one time with Bobs keyset. The problem: They both don't trust each other. So we can't send Bobs public key to Alice in order to double-encrypt, because Bob can't trust Alice that she stores the generated secret value before encryption.

My second approach is to write a software tool that generates the secret value and immediately encrypts it with Alices and Bobs' public key. But if Alice runs this software, how can Bob be sure that the encrypted hash he got was generated from this software tool and not from a compromised tool from Alice?

I hope the idea is understandable. Which approaches could solve this problem? Do I need a third person that does the encryption for them - and what if there is no such person, that Alice and Bob both trust.

Comment: @poncho The value is a private key that was generated. It could have been generated in a closed-source application so that we can be sure that neither Alice nor Bob know it. But then we can't prove that the encrypted value was generated by the software, can we?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve with the encrypted value (the plaintext)? If you don't trust either with the plaintext (the generated secret) then yes, you'd need a third party. You cannot rely on anybody distributing information or keeping information if you don't trust them.

Comment: It seems like your use case calls for [threshold decryption](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/cis-threshold.html) against passive adversaries. ​ ​

Comment: The plaintext of the encrypted value is used to decrypt a secret file (document). But even when a third party exists that creates the keys, than this third party has the key and could decrypt the file on its own. I feel like this is a chicken-egg problem. Basically I'm searching for a way to generate a private key where no! party has the key fully. The only party to trust is the one which has the unencrypted document at start - but this is a closed source software that can't do more (like generating keys).

Comment: Can it _encrypt_ the document? ​ See threshold decryption. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes it can encrypt. But it can't generate the keys on its own. So Alice or Bob has to pass them. And than I'm at the start of the problem.. Is there a more easier explanation how threshold decryption works? I'm trying to get a grasp on it..

Comment: Er, actually it seems like threshold decryption is stronger than what you need. ​ Are you able to choose what encryption scheme the document-creator will use? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It is AES. But I don't want to restrict beforehand. What do you have in mind?

Comment: This might be a long shot, but you could try splitting the key, OR using a secret sharing scheme. www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~cchen/CS4351/ch9.ppt

Check that link out, and see if that helps.

Comment: I had in mind constructing the encryption scheme to facilitate what you're after. ​ If you're limited to a symmetric scheme, the only thing I can think of is using [the sledgehammer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multi-party+computation&t=hk&ia=web) to get the ciphertext for a random [shared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) symmetric key and [encapsulations](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.7813&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of those shares. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I'm not sure that we speak about the same problem.. I try to re-phrase to what I think is the core problem: Can Alice and Bob generate a shared public key using their private keys without Alice and Bob knowing the shared private key?

Comment: Sure. ​ (I was getting the impression that that wasn't enough.) ​ [PKENO](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fuchsbau/PKENO.pdf) plus a [strongly unforgeabl](https://books.google.com/books?id=ketHW15hlJ0C&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=digital+signature+%22strong+unforgeability%22)e [one-time signature scheme](https://wiki.cc.gatech.edu/theory/images/6/6d/Lec13.pdf) is enough to make that fully non-interactive - The "shared public key" is just the sorted pair of their personal public keys, and decryption is also minimally interactive. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (One can use weaker computational assumptions at the cost of getting weaker properties.) ​ ​

Comment: Are there any implementations of that? I'm not a crypto expert myself..

Comment: I've read through the PKENO paper. It seems like that it is like normal PKE, but a third party can verify that a cypher decrypts to a message. Where does that help in my case?

Comment: That stops Alice from making Bob [think overall decryption succeeded but have a wrong thing as the "secret value"], and stops Bob from making doing that to Alice. ​ ​

Comment: @David, I'm not sure if I've got this correctly, but it seems to me that you _are_ going to need a trusted third party to generate and encrypt the secret for Alice and Bob. Any encryption function is going to need the plaintext as input, so any process that does the encryption needs to be trusted to not also leak the plaintext. If you can make software act as the third party, then there you go. But the software will need an admin/operator and a hardware it runs on, and they are subject to the will of at least some person, who you need to trust.

Comment: @David, if you get that trusted third party (be it a lawyer or the boy scout next door), you could program it to follow instructions agreed by A and B to the letter and use any method you like to protect the secret with A and B's keys.